# Fortran logical compare

Tags: fortran, comparison, logical-operators

I do not understand why this one is evaluated as false.

```
A = .false.
B = .true.
```

(A .eqv. .true. .or. B .eqv. .true.) gives me .false.

I have to add parenthesis to make my conditional statement work. Could anybody explain this to me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it's the order of operations. `.or.` I think has a higher order of operations than `.eqv.`

So your statement is equivalent to

```
((A .eqv. (.true. .or. B)) .eqv. .true.)
((A .eqv.     .true.     ) .eqv. .true.)
(     .false.              .eqv. .true.)
                .false.
```

Not sure, though.

Either way, it's easy to force the intended order with parentheses:

```
((A .eqv. .true.) .or. (B .eqv. .true.))
```

(Of course, your example can be condensed into `(A .or. B)`, but I guess that wasn't the point ;) )

Comment: You can be a lot more certain in your answer: it's correct.  See, for example, Table 7.1 of Fortran 2008 for operator precedence.

Comment: Without seeing declarations, etc., it isn't [safe to assume](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29034913) that `A.eqv..true.` can be replaced by `A`.